# Unhandled Exception: Stack Overflow occurs after the Migrating Flutter version from 2.2.3 to 3.10

Tags: flutter, dart, singleton, stack-overflow

After upgrading Flutter from version 2.2.3 to 3.10, you encountered a black screen and the application failed to start. The console displays an "Unhandled Exception: Stack Overflow" error, with a stack trace indicating that the issue is related to the GlobalDataStore class in the global_data_store.dart file.

What are the possible reasons for encountering a black screen and application not starting after migrating Flutter from version 2.2.3 to 3.10, and how can this issue be resolved?

In the console

```
E/flutter (23599): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Stack Overflow
E/flutter (23599): #0      GlobalDataStore._singleton (package:myapp/data/global/global_data_store.dart:6:32)
E/flutter (23599): #1      GlobalDataStore._singleton (package:myapp/data/global/global_data_store.dart)
E/flutter (23599): #2      new GlobalDataStore (package:myapp/data/global/global_data_store.dart:9:12)
E/flutter (23599): #3      new GlobalDataStore._internal (package:myapp/data/global/global_data_store.dart:14:41)
E/flutter (23599): #4      GlobalDataStore._singleton (package:myapp/data/global/global_data_store.dart:6:61)
E/flutter (23599): #5      GlobalDataStore._singleton (package:myapp/data/global/global_data_store.dart)
E/flutter (23599): #6      new GlobalDataStore (package:myapp/data/global/global_data_store.dart:9:12)
E/flutter (23599): #7      new GlobalDataStore._internal (package:myapp/data/global/global_data_store.dart:14:41)
E/flutter (23599): #8      GlobalDataStore._singleton (package:myapp/data/global/global_data_store.dart:6:61)
E/flutter (23599): #9      GlobalDataStore._singleton (package:myapp/data/global/global_data_store.dart)
E/flutter (23599): #10     new GlobalDataStore (package:myapp/data/global/global_data_store.dart:9:12)
E/flutter (23599): #11     new GlobalDataStore._internal (package:myapp/data/global/global_data_store
```

In the  `global_data_store.dart` file as follows,

```
class GlobalDataStore {
  static final GlobalDataStore _singleton = GlobalDataStore._internal();

  factory GlobalDataStore() {
    return _singleton;
  }

  GlobalDataStore._internal();

  String imageUrl = '';
  int userId = 0;
  String nameOfUser = '';
}
```